# Sort NSArray according to NSDictionary

Tags: ios

Let's say if I have an NSArray of NSObjects:

```
{
  person: {
    'id':'A',
    'firstName':'Bob'
  }
  person: {
    'id':'B',
    'firstName':'Chris'
  }
  person: {
    'id':'C',
    'firstName':'Sarah'
  }
}
```

and an NSDictionary of key-values (NSDates)

```
{
  'A':'13:45:12 Tuesday',
  'B':'01:45:12 Monday',
  'C':'05:45:12 Friday'
}
```

and I want to sort the nsarray according to the the nsdictionary according to date (in this case, the order should be [personB, personA, personC]), what would be a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sortedArrayUsingComparator` -

```
 NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    Person *personA=(Person *)a;
    Person *personB=(Person *)b:
    NSDate *first = [keyDictionary objectForKey:personA.id];
    NSDate *second = [keyDictionary objectForKey:personB.id];
    return [first compare:second];
}];
```

Comment: would the reverse of this be [second compare:first]? (descending)